# JavaScript: Accept Division Function as Argument Into Another Function That Returns New Function --> Returns Quotient

Tags: javascript, callback, return, closures, higher-order-functions

I have a function that divides two input arguments:

```
const divide = (x, y) => {
    return x / y;
  };
```

I have a second function that takes the divide function as its input argument and returns a new function.

```
function test(func) {

    return function(){
        return func(); 
    }
}

const retFunction = test(divide);
retFunction(24, 3)
```

I am expecting the returned value to be 8 (24 / 3).  But I'm getting a returned output of 'NaN'.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the possible arguments to the function: `...args`:

```js
const divide = (x, y) => {
  return x / y;
};

function test(func) {
  return function(...args) {
    return func(...args);
  }
}

const retFunction = test(divide);
const result = retFunction(24, 3);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Worth noting that if you're not in an es6 compatible environment, `.apply` is what you do, rather than `(...args)` so you'd do `return func.apply(null, arguments);` instead of `return func(...args);`